# python SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler knowing the port and use the port already opened

Tags: python, sockets, port, socketserver

This is the code which i played, but each time i make a mistake i can't relaunch it.
It says to me that the port / socket is already used
That's the first question
The second one is in my MyTCPHandler how can i kno the port used ?
here is my code :

```
# MetaProject v 0.2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Thanks to :
People from irc :
Flox,Luyt
People from stack Overflow :
Philippe Leybaert,Platinum Azure,methodin,Suresh Kumar,S.Lott,MatTheCat,
kevpie,Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams,adamk,Frédéric Hamidi,THC4k,THC4k,Blam
"""
import SocketServer
import threading

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024)
        socket = self.request
        print "%s wrote:" % self.client_address[0]
        print self.data
        print self.__dict__
        socket.sendto(self.data.upper(), self.client_address)

def serve_thread(host, port):
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=serve_thread,args=('localhost', 1238)).start()
    threading.Thread(target=serve_thread,args=('localhost', 1237)).start()
    print "toto"
```

i've made :

```
def serve_thread(host, port):
    if port == 1858 :
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), Serverhttp,bind_and_activate=True)
    elif port == 1958 :
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), Serversmtp,bind_and_activate=True)
    server.allow_reuse_address=True
    server.serve_forever()
```

but it doesn't work.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your SocketServer with `bind_and_activate=True` in the call to the constructor.

Then set `server.allow_reuse_address=True`.

If you want to differentiate between the two ports, you can use two different classes for the request handlers.

**Edit**:

Modify your code to look like:

```
def serve_thread(host, port):
    if port == 1858 :
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), Serverhttp,bind_and_activate=True)
    elif port == 1958 :
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), Serversmtp,bind_and_activate=True)
    server.allow_reuse_address=True
    server.server_bind()
    server.server_activate()
    server.serve_forever()
```

It might be cleaner to create your own server class. Something like this:

```
class ReuseAddrServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, (host, port)):
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, (host, port), bind_and_activate=False)
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()
```

Comment: could you be a little more specific please ?

Comment: could you be a little more specific please ? may i make : def serve_thread(host, port):
    if port == 1858 :
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), Serverhttp,bind_and_activate=True)
    elif port == 1958 :
        server = SocketServer.TCPServer((host, port), Serversmtp,bind_and_activate=True)
    server.allow_reuse_address=True
    server.serve_forever()

Comment: @user462794: What doesn't work? You've marked this answer as accepted, so let me know if you're still having trouble.

Comment: I guess you mean `bind_and_activate=False` (and not `True`) after `modify your code to look like` ?

Comment: You can verify if the correct things are happening using ```strace -f -e trace=network ./your-server-command```. Look for a line that says ```setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0```. If you don't see that, then you'll still get Address in Use when there is nothing LISTENING on that port.

Answer (score 12):

It's actually easier than that -- you can just set it as a class variable, rather than overriding **init**. E.g.,

```
class MyServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
```